# CSS | Pseudo elements hover

Tags: css, hover, pseudo-element

I'm having problems with `Pseudo-element`s hover. I tried bunch of stuff to make it work, but no avail. I can't wrap my head around how to make it work, anyone?

**HTML**

```
    <div>
        <header id="header2">
            <ul id="midlist">
                <li class="twitter"><a href="www.twitter.com">Twitter</a>
                </li>
                <li class="facebook"><a href="www.twitter.com">Facebook</a>
                </li>
                <li class="youtube"><a href="www.twitter.com">Youtube</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </header>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
/* -------------------------------------------------*/
/* ----------------hover-------------------------- */

.facebook:before {
content: url(http://nobodyfilm.org/images/Mr.-Nobody-Facebook.jpg);
padding-right: 10px;
position: relative;
bottom: -.4em;
}

.facebook a:hover:before {
content: url(http://nobodyfilm.org/images/Mr.Nobody-Facebook-Hover.jpg);
padding-right: 10px;
position: relative;
bottom: -.4em;
  ;}

.facebook a:hover {color:red;}

/* ----------------hover----------------------------*/
/* ----------------------------------------------- */



.twitter:before{
 content: url(http://nobodyfilm.org/images/Mr.-Nobody-Twitter.jpg);
padding-right: 10px;
position: relative;
bottom: -.4em;
}

.youtube:before {
 content: url(http://nobodyfilm.org/images/Mr.-Nobody-Youtube.jpg);
 padding-right: 10px;
position: relative;
bottom: -.4em;
}


#midlist {
  width:708px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin:0 auto;
    }

#midlist li {
  float:left;
  width:112px;
  height:10px;
  line-height:0px;
  }


#header2 {
  margin-top:2px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  background-color: #191919;
  padding:21px;
  padding-bottom: 51px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VrY4j/4/

Thanks!

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/VrY4j/10/](http://jsfiddle.net/VrY4j/10/)

Comment: This question would get a lot more love if it were in accordance to the guidelines for [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: The description is too short and messy, but at least he posted a Fiddle, and his fiddle is self-explanatory. But Spectre, just linking to a Fiddle is not a good way to go, SO shouldn't rely on external sites for question nor answers, because if these sites are down, SO users won't be able to understand what is the question/answer. I'll edit it for you, do it yourself next time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this

```
.facebook a:hover:before {
```

to this

```
.facebook:hover:before {
```

because you are referring to another object's pseudo element.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VrY4j/12/

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the :before to the a, not the li because you want the whole li to have the hover state.  In the fiddle I only fixed the facebook one.

http://jsfiddle.net/VrY4j/11/

```
.facebook a:before {
content: url(http://nobodyfilm.org/images/Mr.-Nobody-Facebook.jpg);
padding-right: 10px;
position: relative;
bottom: -.4em;
}

.facebook:hover a:before {
content: url(http://nobodyfilm.org/images/Mr.Nobody-Facebook-Hover.jpg);
padding-right: 10px;
position: relative;
bottom: -.4em;
  ;}
```